# AWS Glue pythonshell job - how to connect to elasticsearch in VPC?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-glue, amazon-vpc

Created Pythonshell with simple script, like just `requests.get(<elasticsearch_endpoint>)`. Elasticsearch cluster is in VPC.

I tried using self-referencing groups, endpoints but nothing worked. Also custom connection with JDBC fails `Could not find S3 endpoint or NAT gateway for subnetId` (but it exists).

I see that for Spark jobs ESConnector is available but can not find any working way to make it with Pythonshell jobs. Is there any way to allow such connection?

Comment: Are you using the aws elasticsearch service. You will need to check the cluster to see if it’s accepting connections from everyone in the vpc or if it’s based on Iam roles. There are various settings that may prevent traffic from unauthorised person(s)

Comment: @Emerson Everything from VPC is authorised to interact with AWS Elasticsearch cluster, so this is not the case.

Comment: To discount the obvious. The security group rules do also allow http/https outbound connections as well im hoping. Are you getting a timeout error with the requests module ?

Comment: Yes, security groups are also open to all traffic in/out. Yes, timeout error is thrown from requests.

Comment: Solved, I was missing route to NAT gateway in private subnet.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I was missing route to NAT gateway in private subnet.